# Create Recursive MenuStrip With MySQL C#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, menustrip

I have the next tables nodes.

---

### 1. SubModules.

```
  sub_id  sub_name          subid_parent
  1       Articulos         NULL
  2       Proveedores       NULL
  3       Presentaciones    1
  4       Categorias        1
  5       Subcategorias     4
  6       Pasillos          1
  7       Compras           2
```

---

### 2. ModulesOptions.

modoption_id   modoption_name           sub_id

```
1              Nuevo Articulo           1
2              Modificar Articulo       1
3              Nuevo Proveedor          2
4              Modificar Proveedor      2
5              Nueva Presentacion       3
6              Modificar Presentacion   3
7              Nueva Categoria          4
8              Modificar Categoria      4
9              Nueva Subcategoria       5
10             Modificar Subcategoria   5
11             Nuevo Pasillo            6
12             Modificar Pasillo        6
13             Nueva Compra             7
14             Modificar Compra         7
```

### Now i want to create a recursive menustrip something like this.

```
Articles                                             Proveedores
   L Nuevo Articulo                                     L Nuevo Proveedor
   L Modificar Articulo                                 L Modificar Proveedor
   L Presentaciones                                     L Compras
       L Nueva Presentacion                                 L Nueva Compra
       L Modificar Presentacion                             L Modificar Compra
   L Categorias
       L Nueva Categoria
       L Modificar Categoria
       L SubCategoria
           L Nueva SubCategoria
           L Modificar SubCategoria
   L Pasillos
       L Nuevo Pasillo
       L Modificar Pasillo
```

### This is my Code.

```
DataSet DataSet = new DataSet();
DataSet.Tables.Add(DataTable_SubModules); // Loaded from Database
DataSet.Tables[0].TableName = "SubModules";

DataSet.Tables.Add(DataTable_ModulesOptions); // Loaded from Database
DataSet.Tables[1].TableName = "Modules_Options";
```

ThankYou in advance (y).

Comment: It is very unclear what you're asking - detail what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

```
MenuStrip menuStrip = new MenuStrip();
List<ToolStripMenuItem> items = new List<ToolStripMenuItem>();
for(int a = 0; a< dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count;a++){

    ToolStripMenuItem item = new ToolStripMenuItem();
    item.Name = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[a]["sub_name"];
    item.Text = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[a]["sub_name"];
    items.Add(item);
    int parent = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[a]["subid_parent"];
    if(parent == null) //this wont work btw since you cant null int, i would suggest you use 0 as no parent instead
        menuStrip.Items.Add(item);
    else
        items[parent-1].Items.Add(item);
}

for(int a = 0; a< dataSet.Tables[1].Rows.Count;a++){

    ToolStripMenuItem item = new ToolStripMenuItem();
    item.Name = dataSet.Tables[1].Rows[a]["modoption_name"];
    item.Text = dataSet.Tables[1].Rows[a]["modoption_name"];
    int parent = dataSet.Tables[1].Rows[a][" sub_id"];
    items[parent-1].Items.Add(item);
}
```

Try this and change

```
DataSet DataSet = new DataSet();
to 
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
```

Since you are calling it the same name as the class. And as i mentioned dont null stuff in databases use a difrent approach like using 0 for a menu item with no parents (directly on the menustrip)